# eager load model ids only

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, eager-loading

Using Laravel 5.1, I have deeply connected and nested models for my HTML5 game. When the player logs in, it loads their profiles.

Each profile has `m:m` completed quests, `m:m` completed tasks, `m:m` completed minigames, etc.

The quests/tasks/minigames are `belongsTo` relationship, i.e., Task `belongsTo` Quest, Minigame `belongsTo` Task, etc.

Eager loading these on the user->profile then takes a ton of time.

What I need to do instead then is eager load only the IDs of `tasks`, `minigames`, etc for the profile. I tried this via `$appends`:

```
class Profile extends BaseModel
{
    protected $with = ['game', 'quests'];

    protected $appends = ['task_ids'];

    public function getTaskIdsAttribute()
    {
        return $this->tasks->pluck('id');
    }
```

Still, this loads the models AND an array of task Id values (The loaded `task` models eager load with their related children too.). `tasks` is an array with two eager loads `Task` models:

[image]

I need to speed up login so how can I load IDs only without the rest of the attributes?

---

```
$start = microtime(true);
$user = User::find(Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId(), // how can I add callback here?);
$time = microtime(true) - $start;
```

Comment: Is network transfer or query time the perf bottle-neck?

Comment: @Rafael yes I strongly believe so

Comment: To be sure, please provide network transfer and query time metrics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide tasks, set them as `hidden`:

```
protected $hidden = ['tasks'];
```

To only get the task_id in the query, call the eager/lazy loading with the select function before returning the model:

```
public function loaded()
{
    return $this->load(['tasks' => function($q) {
        $q->select('task_id', 'foreign_key');
    }]);
}
```

Comment: does using `$hidden` still run the query on tasks (to get full task models) for the eager relationship? Meaning, Am I only hiding the return of the task models, but still actually running the query?

Comment: To run a shorter query, call the `loaded` function in my answer before returning the model

Comment: does the `loaded()` function replace `getTaskIdsAttribute()`?

Comment: Okay, but what is actually going on here? Without `loaded()`, and placing model names in `$hidden` array, the `profile` query has already improved vastly. What additional benefit does the `loaded()` function provide beyond `getTaskIdsAttribute` and then using `$hidden` to not load the full models?

Comment: also `tasks` is a `m:m` relationship with `profiles`, so would `task_id` still be `foreign_key`?

Comment: The `loaded` function just replaces a `select *` query on the tasks table with a `select task_id, foreign_key` query.

Comment: Yes for a many to many relationship, there would be no foreign key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181497/discussion-between-growler-and-paras).

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.5+, you can use `$with = ['tasks:id'];`.

Before that, use this:

```
$profiles = Profile::with(['tasks' => function($query) {
    $query->select('id');
}])->get();
```

Comment: im eager loading from the inside the model

Comment: `$appends` doesn't trigger eager loading. It loads the `tasks` relationship for every `Profile` separately. Does your controller return a single profile or multiple?

Comment: its set up for multiple profiles but for this purpose only a single profile

Comment: For a single profile you can just use `return $this->tasks()->pluck('id');`.